# SQL Server 2014 linked server to Pervasive database

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server, pervasive

I'm trying to create a linked server from SQL Server to a Pervasive database.

I have the 64-bit System DSN configured and working:

[ODBC DSN set-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3M59.jpg)

and setting up the linked server thus:

[Linked server set-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlvNW.jpg)

with security set to "Be made without using a security context" (which is correct).

Clicking OK to create, I get this message:

> ===================================
>   The linked server has been created but failed a connection test. Do
>
> ## you want to keep the linked server?
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>   ------------------------------ Program Location:
>      at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String
>   sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType, Boolean retry)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.ExecuteNonQuery(String
>   cmd, Boolean retry)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.LinkedServer.TestConnection()    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.LinkedServerProperties.DoPreProcessExecution(RunType
>
> ## runType, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
>
> The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "WTT" reported an
>   error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>   Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL"
>   for linked server "WTT". (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
>   ------------------------------ For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=12.00.5207&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=7399&LinkId=20476
>   ------------------------------ Server Name: CHOMCHOM\CHOMCHOM Error Number: 7399 Severity: 16 State: 1 Procedure: sp_testlinkedserver Line
>   Number: 1
>   ------------------------------ Program Location:
>      at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction
>   action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean
>   catchException)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String
>   sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType, Boolean retry)

To me, that looks like the linked server can't even see the System DSN. If I do the same with a made up data source (e.g. "WTT-boo"), I get the same message.

I've set these up before in exactly the same way, but can't seem to figure this one out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure why, but arrived at work today with the intention of posting this on another forum, but thought "I'll just try again"......and it worked.

Absolutely no idea what is different today. Server reboot over the weekend maybe??